# LifeRay portlet that use Struts 2, is it an actual technology or is it old stuff?

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, struts2, liferay, portlet

In this time I am working on some LifeRay portlet development project that use Struts 2 as web framework for my portlets. These porltets also use Struts 2 UI tag library for the frontend (wrapping standard HTML and JQuery plugin).

I am absolutly new in this field and I know Spring MVC. I know that I can use Spring MVC into portlet as frontend framework instead Struts 2

I want ask you if you think that these technologies are pretty old and deprecated or if are still actual today ?

Struts 2 still remain an actual and popular framework or nowadays have no sense use it and it is preferable use Spring MVC?

Comment: S2 is not old and not deprecated.

Comment: They've virtually almost the same "age". Conceptually they're both old, but sometimes the alternatives are too young. There is no reason to migrate from S2 to Spring MVC if the requirement is to renew the technology... you need to migrate to Angular, or to something even newer. Spring MVC is neat, while Struts2 has a lot of ready-to-use stuff. I use both, and prefer the latter.  BTW closing for primarily opinion based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not old, and it depends on your requirement as to what you want to use.

For most of the requirements I find that the simple Liferay MVC works just fine instead for going with the heavy-weights with the likes of Spring MVC or Struts2 or JSF.